# NSOutlineView cells are offset

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview, nspopover

I'm trying to show a list in a view based NSOutlineView in an NSPopover. When showing the list, it results in something like this:

[image]

That's not what I set up in IB:

[image]

I'm using a standard non-subclassed NSTableCellView with an NSImageView and an NSTextField as set up for me by IB.

Do you have any idea what could be causing this? I tried reloadData in awakeFromNib. That fixed the first loading, but as I scroll down, the cells are offset again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, turns out turning off Autolayout fixed this.